# Stoping a sound as an action on a node with a key in SceneKit

Tags: audio, action, scenekit

I've written a function in SceneKit that plays background music as an action on a node with a key so I could stop the music playing using the key

I have a global variable so I can call to stop the action from anywhere in the class, (by the way this is SceneKit not SpriteKit, I am still using Swift as a language though)

```
var musicPlayingAction = SCNAction()
```

however nothing stops it, either forKey or removeAllActions as in...

This does nothing

```
scnScene.rootNode.removeActionForKey("bgMusicKey")
```

So I try a higher level and drill down, killing all actions either on the scene, the view or the node (depending on where I attach the sound action).

```
self.scnView.scene!.rootNode.removeAllActions()
```

still nothing...

Even if I run the sound action on a specific node and try to kill that.. you guessed it nothing or should I say the music is still playing.

This is the function

```
func playMusic() {
        if game.state == .Playing {

            let music = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "art.scnassets/Sounds/BgMusic.mp3")!

            music.volume = 0.3;
            music.loops = true
            music.shouldStream = true
            music.positional = false
            musicPlayingAction = SCNAction.playAudioSource(music, waitForCompletion: false)
            scnScene.rootNode.runAction(musicPlayingAction, forKey: "bgMusicKey")
   }
}
```

The Action works as in the music plays but it will not stop.

Is it even possible to stop an AudioSource as an action, I know you can stop Actions with a Key, although this is the first time I have tried to stop an audio SCNAction (note not SKAction) with a key???

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Removed the Action forKey...

Split my game up into scenes, added a game state for each scene, then loaded background music dependant on state & scene.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

There Is An Easy Answer

```
self.rootNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()
```

this would stop all audio players

Answer (score 0):

if you add sound as an action to node you can remove this action with key , if you add sound as audio player you can remove it using remove a `yourNode.removeAllAudioPlayers()`